# Help identifying this old bike please

Tags: road-bike

I've got an offer from a friend to get a bike of his that has been sitting in his attic for a few years now. He says the bike is roughly 25 years old, most probably bought in the Czech republic.
Any idea what this is and is it worth anything? A potential fixup? Unfortunately I've only got one photo..
Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Welcome, evaluation of any worth of any items is specifically off-topic here. Not only prices change in and space but we cannot see any details and anything hidden inside.

Comment: Does it fit you? Do you like it? If yes, it's worth something.

Comment: I only have the photo, @joek . The bike is located on the other side of the country :/

Comment: A few basic measurements would still help you gauge if it can fit you at all. What components does it have? If it’s at least 25 years old, are those the very first Shimano Dura Ace STI shifters? In what condition is the drivetrain, cables, tyres, brake pads, saddle etc.? Considering the age (and storage in a hot attic) it’s likely that rubbers have degraded and you’ll need at least new tyres and brake pads.

Comment: To me this looks rather like a smallish bike. When comparing the size of the bricks to the frame, wheels, bottle and saddle something looks odd.